# SwiftUI border around dynamically shaped View

Tags: swiftui

Sometimes a view's shape can be dynamic like when using the native `.buttonStyle(.bordered)` modifier. This modifier will apply different corner radius based on different button content sizes:

[image: Demo]

#### Question

How can we **stroke** around a custom `view`? (**not** a `Shape`)

---

Considerations after trials:

1. We **can't** use another button with bigger/smaller frame to create the border illusion, because the corner radius will be different and not matched with the original shape
2. The view has transparency, so using `shadow` effect may not be a good option to create the border illusion
3. Using `scale` effect not works as desired, because of the different sizes issue, and also the lack of precise border width
4. `ContainerRelativeShape` is not working (yet) except for widgets

---

Not found solutions to try:

1. Get the `shape` of a `view` to apply `stroke` on it
2. Get the `path` around the content of the `view`
3. apply some sort of **stroke** directly on a `view`

---

#### Sample Code:

```
        VStack {
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .frame(height: 164) // <- Difference
            }
            
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("Hello World")
                    .frame(height: 64) // <- Difference
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        /* .stroke() // something like this, but for a view */
```

Comment: `border` not matches with the `shape` of the `view`. It will create a rectangle outline.

Comment: The .bordered style is not a border, it generate view but not fit to view. Would you add a demo code of the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Asperi, I need to draw a line around a `view` like the `.buttonStyle(.bordered)` (which unfortunately can not apply stroke around it's content). I have added the sample

Comment: A view content might be irregular taking into account compositing/drawing groups, for children it is opaque, so in general it is like raster vectorisation in run-time.

Comment: In `UIKit` there is a property at `button.configuration.background` which has the exact property I need here. Any idea about the `SwiftUI` version? @Asperi

Comment: If you talk only about button (I thought you are about any regular view) then use UIButton representable... I see the same public SwiftUI API as you do - button style customisation is very limited :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, borders are drawn around the frame of a view. If you want to add a border to a rounded view, you need to know the corner radius.

You can hardcode the corner radius of your buttons using the `.buttonBorderShape()` modifier, then overlay your buttons with a shape that matches the shape you choose in `.buttonBorderShape()`

[image]

Comment: Thank but the main point of the question is to have a **dynamic shaped view** and it can not be replaced with a static shape solution.

Comment: your best bet is to build your own ButtonStyle with the appearance you want. The built in button styles are meant to replicate standard iOS system components.

take a look at this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/customizing-button-with-buttonstyle